# How to get source list types of particular list/record field?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Here is I have two entity custom fields with list/record type,

1. custom_dev_j15 entity field has a custom source list (eg: one, two, three, four, etc)

[image]

2. custom_qa_v93 entity field has a standard source list as an object (eg: customer )

[image]

I've two vendor entity custom fields as stated in screenshots of question,

custentity473 --> customer is selected as list source
custentity474 --> custom_dev_j15_m_list as selected as list source ( which is custom list)

Here is snippet that i used to get the options of these fields,

// Snippet

```
var fieldDetails = {};
var record = nlapiCreateRecord("Vendor");
var field = record.getField("custentity473");
var selectoptions = field.getSelectOptions();
for ( var i in selectOptions) {
    var Option = {
        id : selectOptions[i].getId(),
        label : selectOptions[i].getText()
    }
    Options.push(Option);
}
fieldDetail["options"] = Options;
```

But my need is to get source list information like name of the list source (customer or custom_dev_j15_m_list) via suitescript
any idea on how to get this information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this question for what you're trying to do.

In NetSuite almost always, you accommodate to the source list types because you know that's the type, and if you need something else (e.g. a selection which is a combination/or custom selection you'll use a scripted field)

Perhaps you can expand on your use case, and then we can help you further?

Comment: I updated the question description with detailed informations. please refer and provide suggestion. Thanks!